# Curved Scissor Cut in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I'm searching for a good looking solution for drawing a cut with scissor symbols with Tikz.

My starting point, which explains what is to be done looks as follows:

[image: Image of a cut with scissors]

The corresponding current LaTeX/Tikz code looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bbding}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip (-0.5,0.3) .. controls +(1,0.4) and +(-1,-0.4) .. (3.7,0.3) -- (3.7,2) -- (0,2) -- cycle;

\node[fill=blue!20!white,rectangle,rounded corners=0.5cm,thick,inner sep=15pt,draw,anchor=south west] 
   at (0,0) {Hello World};
\end{scope}

\draw[thick,color=black!50!white,dashed] (-0.5,0.3) .. controls +(1,0.4) and +(-1,-0.4) .. 
   node[pos=0.2] {\color{black} \scriptsize \ScissorRightBrokenBottom}
   node[pos=0.4] {\color{black} \scriptsize \ScissorRightBrokenBottom}
   node[pos=0.6] {\color{black} \scriptsize \ScissorRightBrokenBottom}
   node[pos=0.8] {\color{black} \scriptsize \ScissorRightBrokenBottom}
 (3.7,0.3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this is not yet good:

- The scissors are not rotated and located a bit too low.
- The fact that the cutting path is repeated is also not optimal.

So my question is: *How can the quality of the solution be improved* (while, in the optimal case, fixing the redundancy of the cutting path at the same time).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `decorations.markings` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{bbding}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
decoration={markings,
            mark=between positions 0.2 and 0.8 step 0.2
            with { \node[font=\scriptsize,yshift=\pgflinewidth,
                         transform shape] {\ScissorRightBrokenBottom};}}
                ]
\begin{scope}
\clip (-0.5,0.3) .. controls +(1,0.4) and +(-1,-0.4) .. (3.7,0.3) -- (3.7,2) -| cycle;

\node[rounded corners=0.5cm,draw,thick,fill=blue!20!white,
      inner sep=15pt,anchor=south west] {Hello World};
\end{scope}

\path[draw=black!50!white, thick, dashed,
      postaction={decorate}] (-0.5,0.3) .. controls +(1,0.4) and +(-1,-0.4) .. (3.7,0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
now scissor direction follows line as requested in OP comment.

Comment: Thanks! That doesn't rotate the scissors along the path yet, right?

Comment: @DCTLib, ups, you are right. I forgot to add option `transform shape` to the definition of scissor nodes. Corrected and improved their positions now.

Comment: Uuuh, this is pretty nice now!

Comment: @DCTLib, realy? Then the answer may be ripe for acceptance :-)

Comment: Indeed. I'm a fan of following the "wait for 24 hours before accepting a solution - there may be a better one still coming" rule, though.